# How to get first 11800 bytes from response when the file is generated by php does not accept (Range-Bytes)?

Tags: vb.net, request, byte, response

I want to get only 11800 bytes from the response body. I am using this method

```
Public Function getfirstbytes() As String

    Try
        Dim request As HttpWebRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create("http://example.com/nonresumefile.php")
        request.Timeout = 10000

        request.KeepAlive = False
        Dim BYTES_TO_READ As Integer = 11800
        Dim buffer = New Byte(BYTES_TO_READ - 1) {}

        Using resp As HttpWebResponse = DirectCast(request.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
            Using sm As Stream = resp.GetResponseStream()
                Dim totalBytesRead As Integer = 0
                Dim bytesRead As Integer
                Do                        
                    bytesRead = sm.Read(buffer, totalBytesRead, BYTES_TO_READ - totalBytesRead)
                    totalBytesRead += bytesRead
                Loop While totalBytesRead < BYTES_TO_READ
                request.Abort() ' this to cancel the remaining bytes (if is a right way )
            End Using
        End Using
        Dim s = Encoding.Default.GetString(buffer)
        return s
    Catch ex As WebException
        Return Nothing
    End Try
End Function
```

is this gets only the first 11800 bytes or it gets all the response stream and selects the first 18000 bytes ?

Comment: Why do you call `request.Abort()` twice?  You are using `Using` blocks, so there is no need to call `Close` on `resp` or `sm`, the `Using` block will do that for you.  Also, I'm not 100% sure, but I don't think VB.NET supportrs `+=`.  Have you tried running the code to see what it does?

Comment: @Tim thanks for your support ! yes you are right for the notes but whene i inspect the response with fiddler the body is returned all and not only first 11800 bytes

Comment: Not sure on the output you're getting, but an easier way to read the first 11800 bytes would be to change your `Read` line to `bytesRead = sm.Read(buffer, 0, BYTES_TO-READ)` - that will start at position 0 in the stream and read up to the 11,800 byte.  No need to keep track of how many bytes you read nor any need to use a loop.  You will want to check the length of the stream first though; if it's less than 11800 you'll get an ArgumentException error.

Comment: What does your function return?  I would expect the whole body to be there in Fiddler unless you're resending the first 11800 bytes back over the wire and inspecting that.

Comment: 'bytesRead = sm.Read(buffer, 0, BYTES_TO-READ)' is already done because 'TotalBytesRead' is already declared '0'

Comment: @Tim the return is 11800 bytes but i think that i get all the bytes instead only of 11800 first bytes

Comment: Yes, but you have a loop that's not necessary (that was my main point).  If the return is 11,800 bytes why do you think it got all the bytes?  What are you doing with the return value?

Comment: @Tim thanks for the support but i have just tested it with a big file and the return is correct

Answer (score 1):

for who is looking for this case the above code is working correctly

```
Public Function getfirstbytes() As String

    Try
        Dim request As HttpWebRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create("http://example.com/nonresumefile.php")
        request.Timeout = 10000

        request.KeepAlive = False
        Dim BYTES_TO_READ As Integer = 11800
        Dim buffer = New Byte(BYTES_TO_READ - 1) {}

        Using resp As HttpWebResponse = DirectCast(request.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
            Using sm As Stream = resp.GetResponseStream()
                Dim totalBytesRead As Integer = 0
                Dim bytesRead As Integer
                Do                        
                    bytesRead = sm.Read(buffer, totalBytesRead, BYTES_TO_READ - totalBytesRead)
                    totalBytesRead += bytesRead
                Loop While totalBytesRead < BYTES_TO_READ
                request.Abort() ' this to cancel the remaining bytes 
            End Using
        End Using
        Dim s = Encoding.Default.GetString(buffer)
        return s
    Catch ex As WebException
        Return Nothing
    End Try
End Function
```

Comment: Glad its working.  Personally, I'd still get rid of the for loop, even though it will only execute once.  Something like `If sm.Length >= 11800 Then sm.Read(buffer, 0, BYTES_TO_READ) End If`, but that's up to you.